# Finding functions g, such that the definite integral of f*g, where f is a continous function with at least one root, is equal to zero.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider the space of all real valued continous functions f on a closed and bounded interval [a,b] wich have a root c in [a,b]. Find all real valued, continous functions g:[a,b]->R ,such that the definite integral of f(x)*g(x) on [a,b] is equal to zero.

My attempts: I literally have no idea, how to tackle this, probably something about symmetry will be important, but I dont know.

Edit: This problem is from an Linear algebra textbook, where we have to find the orthogonal complement of the described functions f with integral of f*g on [a,b] as the dot product. No specifications have been made regarding [a,b] or attributes about f or g other than already stated.

Comment: It would be helpful to specify (1) The source of this problem (2) Any examples $g(x)$ that you can think of (and justify) for particular values of $c$.

Comment: Use Weierstrass Thereom to show that the only such function $g$ is the zero function.

Comment: Can you please clarify: are looking for all $g$ for which $\int_a^b fg = 0 $ for a *fixed $f$*? Or are you looking for all $g$ for which $\int_a^b fg = 0 $ for *every $f$* in the described space?

Comment: Im looking for functions g such that they are orthogonal to all functions f of that space , so the latter part of your sentence.

Comment: Bump functions - that is continuous functions that are positive in a small neighborhood of some point $p$, and are $0$ everywhere else, are included in your space $\mathscr F$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with a root.